# Not able to get Google Signin Profile Image in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus-signin, googlesigninaccount

I have followed the instructions in this URl and get the userid, name and email but image information is not having. Please suggest your feedbacks.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people

Also use this url to get image https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/115950284...320?fields=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY} but it says

```
{
"error": {
 "errors": [
  {
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
"message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
"extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
 } ], "code": 403,
 "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
} }
```

Comment: Did you, perhaps, specify the domain name of your deployment server in the API key configuration, and then try to run your code from your development machine? You probably need to specify more information of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the server API and write not just IP of the server but also IPv6. This helped me with the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps explain a bit more about how this management of IP addresses works; it might very well be relevant to the question, but currently your answer is too short to be really helpful.